# how to share screenshot to Facebook

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, social-media

I've already done that screenshot part, but still haven't found any solution to share the screenshot image to Facebook by using FBSDKSharePhoto. Facebook doesn't provide enough references for it. Can anyone please guide me here?

Here is my screenshot code just in case:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO , 0.0f);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[[UIColor blackColor] set];

CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);



UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;



[window.layer renderInContext:ctx];

UIImage *screengrab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: This should be what you are looking for: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/facebook-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-facebook-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Comment: no i don't need login function. thank you anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to FBSDKSharePhotoContent and FBSDKShareDialog.  You need to setup your content as a photo(s):

```
UIImage *screengrab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[[FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImage:screengrab userGenerated:YES]];

// Assuming self implements <FBSDKSharingDelegate> 
[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

Comment: What is happening?  Have you setup the FBSDKSharingDelegate?

Comment: yes. it returns this "sharer:didFailWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e6d4c0'"

Comment: I've figured it out with the help of your answer. thanks